# NBMongo not working in NetBeans 8.2?

Tags: mongodb, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I have NetBeans 8.2 and have installed MongoDB version 3.4.1. I saw NBMongo plugin for NetBeans and installed it via Plugin manager.Restarted the IDE a zillion times but NBMongo doesn't show up in the services tab. Anybody else having this problem?
How do i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to download the plugin for version 8.2 [from the netbeans website](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52638/nbmongo) and install it manually.